# PHP website returning different SHA512 values for Desktop and Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, php, android, mobile, sha512

I am working on a website which requires a membership section. So, when the user registers a new members account, I am saving the username, a random salt, and a SHA512 hashed password using the random salt and the user's password in order to not save the password in plain text in my database.

The problem I seem to have when a user logs in is that the SHA512 javascript function is returning a different value when I'm using the website from my desktop vs. from a mobile browser (both Android and IOS devices). The desktop appears to be the correct one.

Here is the PHP function I'm using to check when the user logs in:

```
// login function, check email and password against the database.
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
// Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt 
    FROM members
   WHERE email = ?
    LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
    $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();

    // get variables from result.
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
    $stmt->fetch();

    // hash the password with the unique salt.
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
        // from too many login attempts 

        if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Account is locked 
            // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
            $_SESSION['temp'] = "account locked.";
            return false;
        } else {
            // Check if the password in the database matches
            // the password the user submitted.
            if ($db_password == $password) {
                // Password is correct!
                // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

                $_SESSION['temp'] = $user_browser;

                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                            "", 
                                                            $username);
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                          $password . $user_browser);
                // Login successful.
                return true;
            } else {
                // Password is not correct
                // We record this attempt in the database
                $now = time();
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                $_SESSION['temp'] = "Invalid password. ";// . $username . " " . $password . " " . $db_password;                
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['temp'] = "User not Found.";
        // No user exists.
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Here are the SHA values I got from the same username/password:
Desktop (which let me log in correctly):  091b2e6cda1e1ee4de89b1164703a238021fa6c092551cfea2c967051bd01f3992dbe160bbc25a14694f119a819b88534b21d0f7c8da9c80bb8c06a79f75074c

From my Android phone (Invalid password returned):20036264d5fccd56658e45364112ae0e3356878d84150aa817e049a288aa491b88fab9384df71a3aae7e3d0145acd3dc5608030961181b1bf8336e6019824daf

The javascript SHA512 function I'm using can be found here: http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5

Comment: Why do you want to hash the password in javascript, so most likely on the client side? That does not make any sense. You send the unhashed password and hash it on the server side! Your hashing algorithms are an internal thing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this anomaly is because of the representation of characters. In different OSs, browsers and devices the representation may be different. Try converting the password to a common format such as UNICODE , before calculating the digests.

In php you can use [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) function.

in javascript

```
function encode_utf8( s ) {
  return unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
}

function decode_utf8( s ) {
  return decodeURIComponent( escape( s ) );
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't change the returned hash values